# Why Nsmutablearray losing their values?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why NSMutableArray object in objective c losing their values suddenly ?

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSMutableArray *myArr
```

Comment: Alloc it Before to use it . Becoz weak doesn't occupy any memory . It takes only reference.

Comment: You need to show more details about how this is being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your code ...

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

ARC conversion tool changed the properties of custom object and don't make pointer weak if you are allocating memory for it and also using widely in your project .

Comment: I have created one room. can you try this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49997/ios-developers-india

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `weak` to `strong`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArr
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

A **weak** reference does not imply ownership, and does not keep an object alive. Use strong property to retain object. **The opposite to weak is strong.** There’s no need to specify the strong attribute explicitly, because it is the default.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *myArr
```

See [this apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) to know more about weak VS strong.